# How do I return an array of int from C++ to VB.NET in a DLL?

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, dll

I have a DLL function and I want this function to return an array of integers.

My function definition is as follows:

```cpp
extern "C" void HelloWorldArray(int * &A) {

    std::vector<int> *pVectorA = new std::vector<int>;

    pVectorA->push_back(2);
    pVectorA->push_back(4);
    pVectorA->push_back(8);
    pVectorA->push_back(16);
    pVectorA->push_back(32);

    A = pVectorA->data();

}
```

As far as I know, this effectively returns the address of the vector which in C++ guarantees that it can be exchanged by the address of an equivalent array because vector guarantees contiguous memory location. I have also read that using new for the vector stores both vector header and vector data in the heap and hence can be consumed outside the function.

In VB.NET I try this:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("dll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function HelloWorld(ByVal x As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    Private Declare Function HelloWorld Lib "dll.dll" (int) As Integer
    Private Declare Function HelloWorldArray Lib "dll.dll" (int())

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim j As Integer()

        HelloWorldArray(ByRef j as Integer())
        Console.WriteLine(j)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Which does not even compile, it gives `BC30201 Expression expected.` for line `Private Declare Function HelloWorldArray Lib "dll.dll" (int())`.

Any tips on how to return an array of an unknown length from C++ to VB.NET is welcomed.

Note: the array needs to be passed by reference in the arguments, not as return element, because in the real application several arrays need to be moved back to VB.NET.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You have to get the C++ code right first to have any hope of writing the corresponding vb.net declaration.  Right now it has a massive memory leak, new[] needs to be paired with delete[] to release the allocated memory.  And that delete[] statement can't be written inside the function since that causes a dangling pointer bug.  One standard strategy is to let the caller supply the array storage, the signature is then int HelloWorldArray(int* buffer, int bufferSize).  Very efficient, now it gets easy on the vb.net side as well.

Comment: Thanks Hans, the problem is that I do not know in advance how large is going to be the array.  Regarding the memory leak, thanks for highlighting the risks.